# I have a SQL Server file backup file (.bak) i want to get detail of each transaction

Tags: sql-server, database, logfile, audit-logging

I have a SQL Server backup (`.bak`) file, and I want use `fn_dump_dblog` (undocumented function) on it to get all transaction history from it.

I read this article https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3555/read-sql-server-transaction-log-backups-to-find-when-transactions-occurred/

and do the same but `fn_dump_dblog` result only shows query of restoring of that database (most of the rows are NULL)

Please help me - what am I doing wrong? Or there is any alternative way to do that?

Note: I am taking backup in full mode

- I already tried `fn_dblog` but that does not help me
- I can not use `fn_dblog` or `fn_dump_dblog` on database directly so I am taking backup (`.bak` file) every day and then restore it to my local system.
- can i get transaction history if i have .trn file  ?

Comment: If it's SQL Server, then don't tag Oracle or MySQL please. It only confuses matters. I've removed these conflicting tags for you. Thanks.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  SQL Server <> MySQL <> Oracle!!!

Comment: And don't edit the tags back in afterwards...

Answer (score 4):

You can't. A database backup only contains a minimal amount of log records, see [How much transaction log a backup includes](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/more-on-how-much-transaction-log-a-full-backup-includes/). If there was no other activity, then the only transaction captured would be the BACKUP itself, as you see.

You did not specify if is a database backup or a log backup, I made an educated guess that you have a database backup. A log backup would contain only log records, but log backup implies a recovery plan and a log chain, you would have mentioned if they were in place.

Comment: can i get transaction history if i have .trn file